# Wordpress span insert for WCAG

Tags: html, wordpress, wcag, wcag2.0

Is there any way to remove that erros to pass the wcag certificate?
You can see the photo with the errors here:

https://prnt.sc/20xrbrx

Must have 0 errors to pass that certificate,

I searched and i see that if insert  an extra  span like

```
 <span class="sr-only">Visit example.com</span>
```

or some elements in html will fix the problem,
But i dont know how can i add custom alt texts or `<span>`

Answer (score 0):

I ran the [WAVE tool](https://wave.webaim.org/extension/) on https://dev.netgen.gr (as shown in your screenshot) and it only shows 4 errors compared to 32 errors in your screenshot.

[image]

There are two "empty button" errors because of the next/prev buttons on your carousel just have an embedded `<svg>` and don't have a label that a screen reader can announce.

[image]

```
<button type="button" class="slick-next slick-arrow" style="">
  <span class="svg-icon icon-right">
    <svg>
      <use xlink:href="#right"></use>
    </svg>
  </span>
</button>
```

You'll need an `aria-label` on the button such as

```
<button type="button" class="slick-prev slick-arrow" style="" aria-label="previous">
...
<button type="button" class="slick-next slick-arrow" style="" aria-label="next">
```

There's one "empty form label" error message on your search field because, similar to the buttons, you have an embedded `<svg>` as the label.

```
<label>
  <span class="svg-icon icon-search size-normal search-icon">
    <svg role="img">
      <use href="#search" xlink:href="#search"></use>
    </svg>
  </span> 
  <input type="text" name="s" class="search-field focused" value="" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">
</label>
```

Your `<input>` is wrapped inside the `<label>`, which is fine, but there isn't any text for the screen reader to announce.  Your `<svg>` has `role="img"` but it also needs an `aria-label`.

```
    <svg role="img" aria-label="search">
      <use href="#search" xlink:href="#search"></use>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, Yes i tried to reduce most of them problems, but i stuck on 4 problems, I aggree with the fixes , the main problem is that cant find the way to insert that codes on the wordpress elements, 
This is an wpbakery element, is there any way to change that?
https://prnt.sc/20xw37e

Comment: I don't know anything about wordpress.  I was just commenting on the errors from the Wave tool.